# Convergence of sequence of functions $nx$ in $[0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series

For each $n\in N$, let $$f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}nx & 0\leq x\leq \frac {1}{n}\\
1 & \frac {1}{n}\leq x\leq 1\\
\end{array}\right.$$

Show that the sequence converges to a function $f$ on $[0,1]$.

Show that $f$ is not continuous on $[0,1]$.

My attempt:

$$0\leq x\leq \frac {1}{n}$$
$$\Rightarrow 0\leq nx\leq 1$$
Now, as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $\lim_{n \to +\infty}{nx}$ does not exist and so the function isn't pointwise convergent. But then again $nx$ here is bounded and $f_n(x)$ is given to be convergent. Please tell me where I'm wrong?

Also, I'm guessing $x=\frac{1}{n}$ will be a point of discontinuity?

Comment: Your sequence of functions converges pointwise towards the function whose value in zero is zero, one in any other point of $[0,1]$. Such a function is not continuous in zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw a picture you can probably see what is going on. $f_n$ increases from 0 to 1 linearly on the interval $[0,1/n]$ and then is constantly $1$ thereafter. Since $f_n(0) = 0$ for any $n$, you have $f(0)=0$. For any $x>0$, we can take $N>1/x$, then if $n \geq N$ we have $f_n(x) = 1$. Thus $f$ is the indicator function of $(0,1]$, which is not continuous on $[0,1]$.

$f_n(x) = x^n$ on $[0,1]$ is a similar example.

Comment: Graph helps me understand, but I need a proof that doesn't involve graph.

Comment: I essentially wrote the formal proof already.

Comment: Graphs do suggest proofs.

Comment: @Ian yes you did, I'm just saying, I need the formal proof :) One last thing, indicator function is the same as limit function, right?

Comment: @Diya The indicator function of a set $A$ is $1$ if the argument is in $A$ and $0$ otherwise.